# Is this documentation correct?( Yes/No answer is enough for me )

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm really confused how should I document these three methods ( onKick, offKick, triggerKick ) :

```
var events = $( {} ); // jQuery Pub/Sub .

/**
 * Creates a football player .
 * @constructor
 */
function Player() {
 ...
}

Player.prototype = {
    ...,
    /**
     * Subscribes a function to the kick event .
     * @param  {Function} fn An event handler .
     */
    onKick: function( fn ) {
        events.on('kick.FootballGame', fn);
    },

    /**
     * Unsubscribes a function from the kick event .
     * @param  {Function} fn The event handler .
     */
    offKick: function( fn ) {
        events.off('kick.FootballGame', fn);
    },

    /**
     * Kicks the ball .
     * @fires kick.FootballGame
     */
    triggerKick: function() {
        events.trigger('kick.FootballGame');
    },
    ...
};
```

#### Is this documentation correct? Yes/No answer would be really appreciated .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you are close to a well-documented script block. I would propose a few changes, illustrated on your code:

```
/**
 * Creates an new Football Player.
 * @constructor
 */
function Player() {
 ...
}

Player.prototype = {

    /**
     * Subscribes a function to the kick event.
     * @param {function} fn - an event handler.
     */
    onKick: function( fn ) {
        events.on('kick.FootballGame', fn);
    },

    ...
};
```

**General rules:**

- no blanks between the last word and dot in a line
- no more than one blank between words
- separate the parameters and their purpose with a dash
- follow the case of the variable types (if applicable), i.e. `{function}` rather than `{Function}`

Comment: You're AWESOME, I can't thank you enough . Thanks a million .

Comment: @CryptoBird You are very welcome :-). And honestly, I didn't have to correct much ;-). Another last comment in general regarding documentation: generate the documentation and read the result. If you feel that enough details are contained and each part is documented, no need to change your inline doc blocks. If you get the feeling that things are not perfect, rework that part. Happy cod'ing!

Comment: I don't know what to say, you gave me much more than I expected. Man, you rock!.